# Real division with arbitrary-precision discrete integers, how to?

Tags: discrete-optimization

I need a reliable arbitrary-precision division of discrete real numbers (ℝ), using arbitrary-precision discrete integers (ℤ).

It is a classic problem, but it is not easy to verify the good solutions on the Web. I need a **division algorithm** to calculate $N/D$ with the following "real life" **computational constraints**:

1. The result can represented as "integer part" and "fractional part", that is ordinate pair  $r=(i,f)$, or by a integer and a standard divisor like $10^n$.
2. The algorithm is a function $f(N,D)$ that use bitwise operations and/or basic  arithmetic operations; and a fast function like $SRT(n_0,d_0)$, that returns the quotient $Q_0$ and the remainder $R_0$, so it returns the pair  $(Q_0,R_0)$.

All values ($i,f,n_0,d_0,Q_0,R_0$) are arbitrary-precision discrete integers ([example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt))... How to calculate? Are there optimized algorithms to do it?

---

**COMMENTS**

In nowadays is commom to use [floating-point arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic) with a reasonable number of bits (e.g. 32)... And to ignore the precision problems. In general programming languages offer simgle and double precision, but no [Quadruple-precision floating-point data type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadruple-precision_floating-point_format).

When you can not ignore precision problems, the programming languages also offer some alternative, such as the arbitrary-precision discrete integers (e.g. Javascript offer [BigInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt)), but it only offers [integer division algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_algorithm), with quotient *Q* and remainder *R*. No function to return "integer part" and "fractional part" (that's what I need).

Related question [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/46864/70274) have good clues, but no objective answer about best algorithms (to obtain "integer part" and "fraction part" from integer division).

Comment: How do you intend to represent your "real numbers"? As a large integer times a power of ten (often a negative power)? Or do you want to work in powers of two? How many digits do you want to store for the result of $1/3$?

Comment: Hi @DavidK, I edited, please check if now better... Well, specifically, and imagining a to store in Javascript (BigInts), as the pair `r=[0n,3333333333333333333333333n]`... Or by a single integer (using a reference like $2^{512}$ to divide it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given positive integers $\ N, D,\ $ and $\ P>0.\ $
 Define $\ I := \lfloor N/D\rfloor\ $ while the remainder
$\ R := \mod(N,D)\ $ or $\ R := N - I\cdot D.\ $ The fractional part
$\ F := \lfloor (10^P \cdot R) / D\rfloor.\ $ The result returned is
$\ (I, F)\ $ which represents $\ N/D \approx I + F/10^P.$

Comment: Yes ... For an obvious question, an obvious answer. It is  perfect!  Except by  a small notational improvement, $\ F := \lfloor (10^P \cdot R) / D\rfloor.\ $